# Disabling/Enabling interrupts on x86 architectures

Tags: x86, kernel, driver, interrupt, netbsd

I am using NetBSD 5.1 for x86 systems. While studying some driver related code, I see that we use ***splraise*** and ***spllower*** to block or  allow interrupts. I searched some of the mechanisms on internet to understand how these mechanisms work in reality. Did not get any real info on that.

When I disassembled I got the mechanism but still do not understand how all these assembly instruction yield me the result. I know x86 instruction individually, but not how the whole stuff works in its entirety.

Need your help in understanding its principles for x86 system. I understand that we need to disable **Interrupt Enable (IE)** bit, but this assembly seems to be doing more than just this work. Need help.

```
  (gdb) x/50i splraise
   0xc0100d40:  mov    0x4(%esp),%edx
   0xc0100d44:  mov    %fs:0x214,%eax
   0xc0100d4a:  cmp    %edx,%eax
   0xc0100d4c:  ja     0xc0100d55
   0xc0100d4e:  mov    %edx,%fs:0x214
   0xc0100d55:  ret
   0xc0100d56:  lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
   0xc0100d59:  lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi
   (gdb) p spllower
   $38 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xc0100d60
   0xc0100d60:  mov    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0xc0100d64:  mov    %fs:0x214,%edx
   0xc0100d6b:  cmp    %edx,%ecx
   0xc0100d6d:  push   %ebx
   0xc0100d6e:  jae,pn 0xc0100d8f
   0xc0100d71:  mov    %fs:0x210,%eax
   0xc0100d77:  test   %eax,%fs:0x244(,%ecx,4)
   0xc0100d7f:  mov    %eax,%ebx
   0xc0100d81:  jne,pn 0xc0100d91
   0xc0100d84:  cmpxchg8b %fs:0x210
   0xc0100d8c:  jne,pn 0xc0100d71
   0xc0100d8f:  pop    %ebx
   0xc0100d90:  ret
   0xc0100d91:  pop    %ebx
   0xc0100d92:  jmp    0xc0100df0
   0xc0100d97:  mov    %esi,%esi
   0xc0100d99:  lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi
   0xc0100da0:  mov    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0xc0100da4:  mov    %fs:0x214,%edx
   0xc0100dab:  cmp    %edx,%ecx
   0xc0100dad:  push   %ebx
   0xc0100dae:  jae,pn 0xc0100dcf
   0xc0100db1:  mov    %fs:0x210,%eax
   0xc0100db7:  test   %eax,%fs:0x244(,%ecx,4)
   0xc0100dbf:  mov    %eax,%ebx
   0xc0100dc1:  jne,pn 0xc0100dd1
   0xc0100dc4:  cmpxchg8b %fs:0x210
   0xc0100dcc:  jne,pn 0xc0100db1
   0xc0100dcf:  pop    %ebx
   0xc0100dd0:  ret
   0xc0100dd1:  pop    %ebx
   0xc0100dd2:  jmp    0xc0100df0
   0xc0100dd7:  mov    %esi,%esi
   0xc0100dd9:  lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi
   0xc0100de0:  nop
   0xc0100de1:  jmp    0xc0100df0
```

The code seems to be using a helper function ***cx8_spllower*** starting at address **0xc0100da0**.

Comment: [`cli`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cli) clears IF (so this core won't service interrupts), `sti` sets IF again, re-enabling interrupts.

Comment: I'm not sure what this code is doing, but the function names sound more like semaphore lock/unlock.  Is `spl` short for spinlock?  Not sure why it would be using `cmpxchg8b %fs:0x210`.  I guess that's on thread-local storage, that's what `%fs` is normally used for, and that's why it isn't using the `lock` prefix.  (i.e. it provides atomicity wrt. other accesses from the same core, because interrupts can't happen in the middle of one instruction).

Comment: @PeterCordes : On FreeBSD in this context SPL doesn't mean spinlock. It means [S]ystem interrupt [P]riority [L]evel.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing `[E|R]FLAGS.IE` with e.g. `CLI` disables all (maskable) interrupts on a CPU.
For a number of reasons it may be undesirable (e.g. you want to allow some or, perhaps, you don't want overheads of virtualizing `CLI` in a VM).

Another way of achieving the goal is to tell to the interrupt controller (either the old 8259 PIC or the Pentium APIC/IOAPIC) that you don't want to service interrupts whose priority is below a certain level. For that you need to communicate with the controller, which itself may incur additional overhead (talking to both real and virtual hardware is slow).

A variant of the latter is to keep the current interrupt level/priority in a variable and let interrupts come in, but only really service those whose level/priority isn't lower than the current one in that variable. Those unserviced will be marked as pending and will get fully serviced when the current level/priority drops sufficiently low. This is why `splraise()` is much simpler than `spllower()`.

This level/priority variable appears to be named differently in different places and versions of the code: `CPL` (not to be confused with CPU's *current privilege level*), `SPL`(?), `ILEVEL`.

This is my current, limited understanding of the implementation. There are more details to it.

Here are some clues that I've found and used for the answer:

- [SPLRAISE(9)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?splraise+9.i386+NetBSD-7.0)
- [Designing the software specification: Interrupt Priority Level
  Management](https://386bsd.org/releases/porting-unix-to-the-386-a-practical-approach-designing-the-software-specification-article)
- [Very slow I/O under OpenBSD i386 on qemu-kvm from RHEL7rc](http://openbsd-archive.7691.n7.nabble.com/Very-slow-I-O-under-OpenBSD-i386-on-qemu-kvm-from-RHEL7rc-td250324.html#a250330)
- [Kernel Services System Processes in Traditional Unix Kernel](https://studylib.net/doc/8153196/kernel-services-system-processes-in-traditional-unix-kernel)
- [NetBSD's amd64/spl.S](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/trunk/sys/arch/amd64/amd64/spl.S)

Comment: SPL is short for [S]ystem interrupt [P]riority [L]evel

Comment: @Alexey Frunze: All due respect, I already understand the aspects about blocking interrupts at a specific level. I want some pointers on the assembly code above. @ Peter Cordes mentioned of thread local storage when we see %fs register. So I would want to understand, how would that be linked to setting an IPL (interrupt priority level). I know, we need to make certain assumptions here, as to what is stored in that location pointed to by %fs:214. Could it be data structures with info on "current" processor? But how that would translate into real action?

Comment: @ultimatecause Yes, `FS:0` points to the structure specific to the CPU (not some thread). It's common practice, even in the Windows kernel.

Comment: @ultimatecause As for the _real action_, you have two kinds of events upon which things are done: calling `spl*()` functions (most notably, `spllower()`, which ensures servicing of already pending hardware interrupts) and hardware interrupts triggering execution of their ISRs (which mark low level/priority interrupts as pending and service high level/priority ones either immediately or in multiple steps (e.g. a part is done immediately in the ISR while another part can be queued to be done outside of the ISRs, in some thread)).